# error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

**Procedure parameters:**

```
procedure get_user_profile (
    i_attuid in  ras_user.attuid%type,
    i_data_group in data_group_tbl,
    o_user_info_tbl out user_info_tbl,
    o_service_tbl out service_tbl,
    o_user_role_tbl out user_role_tbl,
    o_permission_tbl out permission_tbl,
    o_work_group_tbl out work_group_tbl,
    o_business_domain_tbl out business_domain_tbl,
    o_skill_tbl out skill_tbl,
    retnum               out number
)
```

**Java Code:**

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

String procedureName = "{call get_user_profile(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall =
     new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withCatalogName("ras_user_profile_pkg").withProcedureName(procedureName).declareParameters(
        new SqlParameter("i_ATTUID", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("I_DATA_GROUP", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_USER_INFO_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_SERVICE_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_USER_ROLE_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_PERMISSION_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_WORK_GROUP_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_BUSINESS_DOMAIN_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("O_SKILL_TBL", Types.ARRAY),
        new SqlOutParameter("retnum", Types.NUMERIC));

dataGroup = new ArrayList<String>();

Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hm.put("i_ATTUID", attuid);
hm.put("I_DATA_GROUP", dataGroup.toArray());
hm.put("O_USER_INFO_TBL", Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("O_SERVICE_TBL", Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("O_USER_ROLE_TBL", Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("O_PERMISSION_TBL",Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("O_WORK_GROUP_TBL", Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("O_BUSINESS_DOMAIN_TBL", Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("O_SKILL_TBL", Types.ARRAY);
hm.put("retnum", Types.NUMERIC);

SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(hm);

Map simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

Please help me here (I am new two this), why I am getting this error:

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Comment: The tags `i_ATTUID` looks fishy why don't you try with the exact same case as `i_attuid` as per my knowledge oracle variables are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the procedure's name and not the instruction to call the procedure:

```
String procedureName = "get_user_profile";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue where I have written sql query with parameter incorrectly,

```
String sql = "UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = :column1 WHERE COLUMN_2 =: column2";
```

**As you can see while writing above sql, I have added space by mistake while defining column2 parameter in sql, So below one is the correct**

```
  String sql = "UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = :column1 WHERE COLUMN_2 =:column2";
```

Respective sql parameter is as below

```
SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                        .addValue("column1", data.getColumn1())
                        .addValue("column2", data.getColumn2())
```